# Error on working with operator-new and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I am trying to write a program that requires to enter a natural number n, creates an array of n natural numbers, replaces all prime numbers in the array with zeros, and prints the resulting array to the screen, but it ends with a command not found, please explain to me what I did wrong

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 int *arr ;
 int n;
 for(int i = 0;i < n ;i++ ){
   std::cin>>n;
 }
 arr = new int [n]; 
 for(int i = 0;i < n ;i++ ){
   if(arr[i] % arr[i]/2 == 0 ){
      std::cout << arr[i];
   } else {
     arr[i] = 0;
     std::cout<< arr[i];
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend adding more of your process to the question and the error message you are receiving verbatim and as text (Don't post a picture or a screen shot--people can search that very easily).

Comment: Sit down with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and slowly and carefully explain `for(int i = 0;i < n ;i++ ){
   std::cin>>n;
 }` to it piece by piece..

Answer (score 1):

First, your code doesn't get the value of `n`, you should `cin>>n` and then get the whole array with for loop. In addition, `arr[i] % arr[i]/2` is always zero, because `arr[i] %arr[i]` is zero. You should know how to check whether a number is Prime or not. Here is a  [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-numbers/).

Comment: *First, your code doesn't get the value of `n`* isn't quite true. It will read an undefined number of values for `n`.  Also worth noting that even after the operator precedence is sorted out `arr` points at an array of uninitialized values, so the results of the corrected computation will be undefined.